# Accidentally removed iCloud from Finder siderbar

Tags: macos, finder, icloud, sidebar

I accidentally removed iCloud drive from the Favorites sidebar (in Finder).

Dragging it back isn't restoring it.

How could I restore it?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by going to Finder preferences -> Sidebar and checking iCould Drive

Answer (score 1):

Open Finder preferences and check it again like in the image below.

[image]